# #include errors detected for eigen library

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, include, mingw, eigen

I have been trying to use the Eigen library for c++ in VS code. I have seen various answers explaining how to solve the problem. I have opened the `c_cpp_properties.json`. I have my Eigen library : [image]

But my MinGW shows different files from what I have seen in other answers and tutorials.

[image]

Error in code: [image]

After this, what should I do? I tried adding the include path, but I cannot solve this.
Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Please show a [mre]. What is in your `c_cpp_properties.json`, what is the path to your eigen includes?

Answer (score 0):

You can move the whole Eigen Library to an included folder in `IncludePath`.

This is an example:

`settings.json`

```json
"C_Cpp.default.includePath": [
        "${workspaceFolder}/**",
        "C:\\TDM-GCC-64\\include",
        "C:\\TDM-GCC-64\\lib\\gcc\\x86_64-w64-mingw32\\10.3.0\\include",
        "C:\\TDM-GCC-64\\lib\\gcc\\x86_64-w64-mingw32\\10.3.0\\include\\c++"
    ]
```

For you:

```json
"configurations": [
         {
             "name": "Win32",
             "includePath": [
                 "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                 "C:\\MinGW\\include",
                 "C:\\MinGW\\lib\\gcc\\x86_64-w64-mingw32\\{Your GCC Version}\\include",
                 "C:\\MinGW\\lib\\gcc\\x86_64-w64-mingw32\\{Your GCC Version}\\include\\c++"
             ]
         }
]
```

You can put it in any of the folders like this.

Comment: Do you mean `include` folder in `MinGW`?

Comment: @Avii Yes, you can move it to any of the included folders.

Comment: `{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "C:\\MinGW\\include"`           I am still not getting the problem resolved, `endl` in the code stops working! Could you suggest what should be done?

Comment: Its still showing the error and it cannot find 
                 "C:\\MinGW\\lib\\gcc\\x86_64-w64-mingw32\\6.3.0\\include\\c++".

Comment: i dont think i have `lib\\gcc\\x86_64-w64-mingw32` I dont know how to deal with this

Comment: I downloaded the Eigen library in the downloads file and extract it with the name `eigen - 3.4.0`. Then I cut and paste the file in `MinGW--> include`. as in 2nd screenshot. Then I go to VS code and try to make the changes but it didn't work :( I checked the `g++` version and it gives `C:\Users\Avii>g++ --version
g++ (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1) 6.3.0
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.` Where am I wrong?? @Alan Birtles